# subscribeOn new thread sometimes not returning

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

Could anyone please have a look at the following code and let me know why is this behaving differently:

```
package com.example.rxjava;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MyRxJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("getting sum ... by thread: " +
            Thread.currentThread().getId());
    //        observeOnNewThread();

    subOnNewThread();
    independentProcess();
    }

    private static void observeOnNewThread() {
        Observable.create(new CountObservable(100)).observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer a) {
                System.out.println("processing dependent process " + a + "  ..... by thread: "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        });
    }

    private static void subOnNewThread() {
        Observable.create(new CountObservable(100)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer a) {
                System.out.println("processing dependent process " + a + "  ..... by thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        });
    }

    private static void independentProcess() {
        System.out.println("precessing something else .... by thread: "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.rxjava;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;

public class CountObservable implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer> {

private int value;

public CountObservable(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
    System.out.println("calculating sum ....  by thread: "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());

    int tot = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k<=value; k++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tot+=k;
    }



        subscriber.onNext(tot);
        subscriber.onCompleted();
  }
}
```

sometimes it prints

```
getting sum ... by thread: 1
precessing something else .... by thread: 1
```

and sometimes

```
getting sum ... by thread: 1
precessing something else .... by thread: 1
calculating sum ....  by thread: 11
```

Anyway it is not printing the message inside the

```
@Override
public void call(Integer a) { ... }
```

method

And when I run the `observeOnNewThread()` method it works, but I want to calculate the sum in a different thread

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: since It involves two classes, I'll share my github link as well
https://github.com/user392919/hello-rx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/rxjava/MyRxJava.java
https://github.com/user392919/hello-rx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/rxjava/CountObservable.java

Comment: @user392919 Please read the user guidelines for Stack Overflow.  Your code should be placed inside your question.  Do not link to outside sources.

Comment: Sorry about this I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJava schedulers run on daemon threads and your main method completes before they had a chance to run to completion. You have to await them in some way: by sleeping in main, by using `toBlocking().forEach()` or the other `toBlocking()` methods.

Comment: Thank you !, now I changed my code as 
`private static void subOnNewThread() {
        Integer a = Observable.create(new CountObservable(100)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).toBlocking().first();
                System.out.println("processing dependent process " + a + "  ..... by thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }`
it works, but how can I run the dependent process, in a different thread (if possible pls check MyCallback sample)

Comment: `flatMap` over the result of your primary Observable.